# Configuring assets for analyzers packages

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, static-analysis, package-management

My solution consists of multiple projects. In the root we have `Directory.Build.props`

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SonarAnalyzer.CSharp" Version="8.51.0.59060" Condition="$(MSBuildProjectExtension) == '.csproj'">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.118" Condition="$(MSBuildProjectExtension) == '.csproj'">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

These static code analyzers are using only during development. I see that I can configure assets and prevent exposing these packages. My solution structure:

- ServiceA.Api.csproj
- ServiceA.Core.csproj
- ServiceA.Domain.csproj
- ServiceA.Infrastructure.csproj
- ServiceA.SDK.csproj

What are the implications for setting `PrivateAssets` and `IncludeAssets` in certain ways? What practice for the values of these makes sense in the context of analyzer packages?

Answer (score 0):

If the analyzers are only used for development on the developer's machines, I recommend accepting the package references however NuGet adds them, and then conditionally only including them using the parent `<ItemGroup>` in your DevOps pipeline. This usually means only include them for `Debug` but not `Release`.

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

If that is not granular enough (e.g. when you want to build both `Debug` and `Release` locally and/or in the pipeline, or you want the analyzers to run during DevOps pipeline exection always), you can take the advice in [Controlling dependency assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets).

There is no one best practice for this because requirements vary. The defaults are most likely what you should start with because the defaults are chosen for a reason.

The defaults, as mentioned in the content for the above link, are

- `IncludeAssets` --> `all`
- `ExcludeAssets` --> `none`
- `PrivateAssets` --> `contentfiles;analyzers;build`

Unless you are optimizing the size of your final solution, trying to prevent exposure of analyzers to prevent some sort of security issue or misuse, or otherwise trying to avoid some sort of problem, I would say, "just use them as they are, assets set to the values NuGet used when adding the analyzer package".